# php echo html without quotes and whitespace

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo auto-generated html form elements, but the page always shows html code as text. When I check the output via Chrome, it shows generated form input with quotes and whitespaces. Here is what I have tried and results:

Here is code generates entire form

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('/survey/submit?id='.$Survey->getId()) ?>" method="post">
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($Questions as $Question): ?>
        <li><?php echo $Question->questionHtml() ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And here is a sample result:

```
"<li>
                                <input class="survey" size="40" type="text" name="Sample Survey[input_1]" id="Sample_Survey_input_1" />             </li>"
```

I tried htmlentities also.

```
echo htmlentities($Question->questionHtml())
"
                                &lt;input class=&quot;survey&quot; size=&quot;40&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;Sample Survey[input_1]&quot; id=&quot;Sample_Survey_input_1&quot; /&gt;             "
```

**The problem is I couldn't get these generated form elements displayed on the page, but only plain text format of them.**

Comment: What's the problem here? The first one echoes HTML, the second echoes encoded HTML ...

Comment: Can you please show us the lines that precede this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its showing the code you need to decode the html entities

```
echo html_entity_decode( $Question->questionHtml() );
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

**BUT**

This shouldn't have to be done.  The questionHtml() function should only turn the form values into their entities, not the entire form.

Answer (score 0):

If `$Question->questionHtml()` is echoing the correct HTML, then all you need is to use `trim()` to remove the whitespace.